# How efficient are Azure Service Bus correlation filters?

Tags: azure, websocket, chat, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

**TL;DR; - I want to use 10k-100k correlation filters on an ASB topic to route incoming messages to websocket servers to deliver notifications to users.**

Context: I am trying to come up with a design for a distributed notification delivery system that uses a WebSocket (WS) server cluster to deliver notifications (including chat and user account events) to clients connected to the WS servers. Obviously, since the WS connections are sticky between client and WS, when an event is emitted somewhere in my system, to get it delivered to the right client I need to know to which WS server should process the message.

While I don't want to use Redis pub/sub because of a lack of acknowledgement capability or queuing, RabbitMQ seems like it would fit the bill: I can set up a direct exchange such that whenever a WS server is spun up, it creates a new queue under that exchange, and every time a client connects to the WS server, I add a new binding key (equal to the user ID) between the exchange and the WS server's queue. This way, when an event is published to the exchange with a given user ID, all WS servers will get the message in their queues for processing.

However, I would not like to manage my own RabbitMQ cluster - neither for setup/config reasons nor for cost reasons. Given that my app will likely be hosted on Azure, I might as well take advantage of Azure Service Bus. Until recently, I didn't know it could handle a workload like this, but I just read that if I use topics (equivalent of RMQ exchanges), each WS server can create its own subscription (equivalent of RMQ queue) and add a filter to that subscription so that when a message with certain properties is published to the topic, the subscription (ie, WS server's queue) will get the message delivered to it after filtering. *The setup would be that every time a client connects to a WS server, that server would add a new filter to its subscription equal to the user's ID.*

What this means is that if I have 10k active users with WS connections, there would be 10k filters set on my topic.

I am interested in **two main things** (but more perspective is appreciated!):

1. Is adding a new feature to a subscription on the fly fast and CPU/memory efficient?
2. Is having 10k correlation filters (and maybe more! ASB seems to support up to 100k correlation filters on a topic) going to increase my latency too much if I'm ingesting something like 100 messages per second? I'd love my end-to-end latency of (event published to ASB)->(client receives message) to be under 100ms. (so ASB uptake, delivery to WS server, and delivery from there to client must be included).

If there are no good or direct answers, I'd appreciate qualitative insights as well :)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read about signalR ? It is websocket server. Azure provides signalr as a service so you don't need to worry about the infrastructure part: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/

Comment: I'm considering different options. The SignalR service has strong advantages of not having to manage infrastructure, but comes with the downside of a bit less control and a cap on maximum resources available (such as concurrent connections). I also suspect I can squeeze out more performance than given by the service by default (1k concurrent connections per hub).

Comment: I guess you can buy multiple unit ? Also I found the pricing fair compare to the price of redevelopping everything on your own. Servicebus could be more expensive depends on the solution you're gonna choose

Comment: For a managed solution you might also consider something like PubNub (https://pubnub.com) for super low latency messaging as well as worldwide connectivity (If that matters for your solution).